# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'kaa::KaaException'

Tags: c++, iot, kaa

I have Problem in Running Notification in the Kaaproject 
after building the application and Run I have this errors

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'kaa::KaaException'
  what():  [Kaa OpenSource Project] Instruction failed! Details: "Failed to add    

   topic list listeners. Notification subsystem is disabled" Original message:            std::exception
Backtrace:
[0] ./client(_ZN3kaa12KaaException12captureStackERSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE+0x43) [0x66a0a7]
[1] ./client(_ZN3kaa12KaaExceptionC2ERKSs+0xe4) [0x669f88]
[2] ./client(_ZN3kaa9KaaClient20addTopicListListenerERNS_30INotificationTopicListListenerE+0x52) [0x66db66]
[3] ./client(main+0x10d) [0x65a03d]
[4] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f8f911d6830]
[5] ./client(_start+0x29) [0x659b39]

Aborted (core dumped)
```

could you please tell me whay i have this type of problem ????

Comment: *"Failed to add topic list listeners. Notification subsystem is disabled"* So you have to enable the subsystem?

Comment: How is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable notification subsystem with the `KAA_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATIONS` CMake option:

`cmake -DKAA_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATIONS=0 ..`

(Note that that's the default value of the option.)